# Easier way to link up Entity Framework Relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-relationship

I have seperated several models for normalization's sake and they all should have a one to one relationship. Due to the difficulty of doing 1 to 1 relationships in EF I have done the following:

```
public class Fleet : SpaceObject
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int? ActiveCaptainId { get; set; }
    public int? ResourcesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ActiveCaptainId")]
    [Display(Name = "Captain in Command")]
    public virtual Captain ActiveCaptain { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResourcesId")]
    public virtual Resources Resources { get; set; }
}

public class Captain
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int? FleetId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FleetId")]
    public virtual Fleet Fleet { get; set; }
}

public class Resources
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int? FleetId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FleetId")]
    public virtual Fleet Fleet { get; set; }
}
```

When a new user is created I:

- First create a Captain
- SaveChanges()
- Then create a Fleet and assign the Captain to the Fleet
- SaveChanges()
- Then create a Resources and assign the Fleet to the Resources
- SaveChanges()
- Then assign the Fleet to the Captain, and the Resources to the fleet.

Like so:

```
 Captain newCapt = new Captain();
 newCapt.Name = model.
 newCapt.UserId = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.UserName == model.UserName).UserId;
 db.Captains.Add(newCapt);
 db.SaveChanges();

 //----Make a new Fleet
 Fleet newFleet = new Fleet();
 newFleet.ActiveCaptain = newCapt;
 newFleet.UserId = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.UserName == model.UserName).UserId;
 db.Fleets.Add(newFleet);
 db.SaveChanges();   //commit the changes to the database

 Resources resources = new Resources();
 resources.Fleet = newFleet;
 db.Resources.Add(resources);
 db.SaveChanges();

 newFleet.Resources = resources;
 newCapt.Fleet = newFleet;
 db.Entry(newFleet).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
 db.Entry(newCapt).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I feel like there has to be an easier way to do this. Is there a way to make it so that once a new Fleet is created it creates a new Resources entry and Ships entry, etc. ? The only reason why I can see that this isn't possible is because I cannot link up a primary key from Fleet to the Resources/Captains/Ships/etc until the Fleet has been saved to the database.